# How to get response content in karate if the json response contains german characters?

Tags: cucumber, karate

I am trying to get GET response in Karate but whenever the response contains non english characters , it returns '???' for the field in the response. 
Instead I want the actual characters to be returned.

```
{Id="abc", name="<Some German Text>"}
```

Actual Response returned :

```
{Id="abc", name="????"}
```

Karate script :

```
  Given path 'URL'
  When method get
  Then status 200
  * json convertJSON = response
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following configuration for the `maven-surefire-plugin`

```
<configuration>
    <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
</configuration>
```

This is how it would look like in a typical `pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10</version>
    <configuration>
        <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Do let me know if this works !